# Логическое OR в условии оператора if

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно, чтобы если int one; или int two; имело значения 0, выполнялся код, я делаю так:

```
if (one == 0 OR two == 0) {
Мой код
}
```

В php бы такое условие выполнилось. Как правильно делать в java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java операция `ИЛИ` записывается как: [`||`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

```
if ((one == 0) || (two == 0)) {
    // код
}
```

Comment: а почему используются две скобки?

Comment: @Денис они объединяют два и более условия

Comment: @m0nhawk, во втором примере отрицания не правильнее ли поставить?

Comment: @Visman да! Исправил.

Comment: одного меня удивляют значения int в операторе if во втором примере?

Comment: @s_klepcha, вы про отрицание только булевых значений?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((one == 0) || (two == 0)) {
Ваш код
}
```